# Disable OPTIONS method call React + Spring boot

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, tomcat, iis

I am having frontend in React and backend in Spring boot. I am having `GET/PUT/POST/DELETE` HttpMethods in Rest API, but for every request from the client `OPTIONS` call is sent by the client(browser). Due to security reasons, I need to restrict these `OPTIONS` method call from the client. At this moment of time changing on API level is not feasible Is there any configuration kind of thing to prevent this.
React application is deployed on IIS and Spring boot application on Tomcat.
React application using `Axios` as HTTP Client.
**Note:** I know the preflight request is sent by browser and for this `OPTIONS` are getting invoked, I don't want to go in that direction.

Comment: what are you using to send the request? are you using axios?

Comment: Yes, Using Axios for API calls. @nasser17

Answer (score 1):

These OPTIONS requests are part of the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) specification which states that every PUT or POSTs with content type application/json must be preflighted with OPTIONS to check `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header without causing any side effects.

I can't see any security issues with allowing OPTIONS, but in fact this is a security feature enforced by your browser.

To stop this behavior you should use same origin requests. Other possibilities which I won't recommend would be to just use GETs for your post requests or POST with content type other that application/json. And of course, you can write your own browser or connect from a native environment (as `HttpClient` on a desktop or mobile app).

Comment: Thanks, @Mordechai, OPTIONS comes under a vulnerable HTTP method that's why I need to restrict this call. Also, I agree to your point that I can use GET and POST(with content type text) but as I mentioned at this moment of time I can't do the changes on the code level.